# NHibernate and Utc datetimes in SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate

Let's consider the following simple class in NHibernate:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
       assembly="MyTests.Tests"
       namespace="MyTests.Tests">
    <class name="TestClass" table="TestTable" dynamic-update="true">
    <id name="Id" column="Id" type="UInt64" unsaved-value="0">
    <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Date1" type="UtcDateTime"></property>
    </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

The class is defined as follows.

```
public class TestClass  {
    virtual public UInt64 Id { get; set; }
    virtual public DateTime? Date1 { get; set; }
}
```

The following usecase produces different results when executed against MySql and SQLite.

```
    [Test]
    public void Test1() {
        //Get Now without Milliseconds
        DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        now = new DateTime(now.Ticks - (now.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond), now.Kind);

        TestClass tc1 = new TestClass() { Date1 = now };
        using(ISession s = NewSession(c))
        using(ITransaction tx = s.BeginTransaction()) {
            s.Save(tc1);

            tx.Commit();

        }

        using(ISession s = NewSession(c))
        using(ITransaction tx = s.BeginTransaction()) {
            TestClass tc2 = s.Load<TestClass>(tc1.Id);
            Assert.IsNotNull(tc2);

            Assert.AreEqual(DateTimeKind.Utc, tc1.Date1.Value.Kind, "Checking kinds of tc1");
            Assert.AreEqual(tc1.Date1.Value.Kind, tc2.Date1.Value.Kind, "Comparing Kinds");

            Assert.AreEqual(now, tc2.Date1, "Comparing datetime values");
        }   
    }
```

The last assert fails when the database used is SQLite.

When I look inside into the SQLite file I can see the date being correct (UTC value).

When it is read back it is read with DateTimeKind.Utc however the *value* is the local time.

This problem doesn't happen if I use MySql.

The table in SQLite is created with CreateSchema by NHibernate and is reported by SQLite Administrator as

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (Id  integer primary key autoincrement, Date1 DATETIME)
```

Dear Gurus, do you know what the problem and solution is? It seems like a problem someone must have seen before...

Thanks
Tymek

Comment: Which version of NH are you using?

Comment: For the record. I have stopped using sqlite in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's an old question, but the answer might help others... If you're using the [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org) provider, you just need to specify `DateTimeKind=Utc` in the connection string. Dates will now be read as UTC.

Comment: This solved my problem for good. Someone should accept this as the solution.

Comment: I haven't confirmed this, but it looks like a valid solution. Accepting.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with sqlite and sql server. I changed all DateTime.Kind to unspecified, then it doesn't change it. I wasn't sure if it is an error on my side and hadn't the time to analyze it any further. If you can isolate the problem and prove that it is a bug, it would be great if you would report it in the [bug tracker](https://nhibernate.jira.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Comment: I stopped using sqlite in the end.